# need to reference 2 different cells and 2 different ranges to find an answer in excel, and put it into the active cell

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, matching, named-ranges

I'm new to excel and I need to find a way to get excel to use "sheet1"B1 
("D") and "sheet1"B3 ("1") in "sheet1" to look up in a range on "sheet2" for some info.

*ex range has 3 columns; A2("D"), B2("1"), C2("01-EC1") - where C2 is the answer I'm looking for.*

Then use that answer (C2 or "01-EC1") to look into yet another range, also on "sheet2", and find the final answer (24). This number is then input into "sheet1"B2 (between the first 2 cells).

Can someone help? The VLOOKUPS and Matches I've been using aren't working, they are coming up "N/A"
Should this be a Macro instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I set up sheet2 like this:

[image]

Then used this formula in B2 on Sheet1:

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet2!A1:A15)/((Sheet2!A1:A15=B1)*(Sheet2!B1:B15=B3)),1)),Sheet2!H:I,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: @MaryKateWyatt did it work for you, if so please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add a column "d" with a value of column "a" & column "b" then using column "d" as the lookup column such that cell D2 would have a value of "D1"

You would need to switch the positions of columns "c" and "d" to do a vlookup iirc as vlookups require the lookup column to be the leftmost column.

It also might be an idea to add another column to sheet 2 which does the second lookup i.e. on row 2 it would lookup "01-EC1" in the second range and put "24" into  cell E2 however depending on the size of your data that will slow down your spreadsheet significantly.

Comment: so instead of the range being: A2("D"), B2("1"), C2("01-EC1") - where C2 is the answer I'm looking for, I would have A2("D"), B2("1"), C2("A,1"),D2("01-EC1") - where D2 is the answer I'm looking for?

Comment: nevermind you meant to look up the second range info into the first range, Column D

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm dumb at times. Currently I'm having trouble typing due to someone trying to put my phone in their mouth.